# Fetching new revisions after a directory move in SVN

Tags: git-svn

I have a git-svn configuration as follows:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    rewriteRoot = http://myproject
    url = http://myserver/myproject/trunk/proj
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

My company decided to move the directory trunk to v100 (at revision xxxxx).

After the move, I updated the url attribute but I am no longer able to do a `git svn rebase`. git-svn chokes with some SVN error (Cannot replace a directory from within).

A fresh checkout fetches only revisions newer than xxxxx.

How can I get all revisions and still have continuous history?

Answer (score 1):

I think we had configured the git-svn sync wrongly. We should have used:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    rewriteRoot = http://myproject
    url = http://myserver/myproject
    fetch = trunk/proj:refs/remotes/git-svn
```

That is, "trunk/proj" should have been part of the "fetch". If I make a fresh `git svn clone` with this, I am able to get previous versions as well.